# Generating TIN, manually modified level curves?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, tin

I'm having trouble while generating a TIN on a manually modified topography file.

I'm new to ArcGIS, but I have intensively tried to fix this bug, with no result.

[image: TIN BUG]

As you can see, the bug deals about continuity in the generated model, the level curves seems to be logically disposed but the generated model proposes a big hole in the ground.

I noticed that the bug (unwanted changing of color = uncontinuity) was triggered by uncontinuous lines, probably created during the manual modification of this curves.

I tried to merge, union, dissolve ans unsplit the lines with no effect on the generated model.

[image: TIN BUG2]

Thus, I'm currently lost and I would like to know if anyone already noticed this bug, and maybe have a piece of solution to give me ?

I'm using on ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: I didn't mentionned, I'm Working on ArcGis 10.1 !

Comment: On the 2nd picture, your selected line has the same Z value as neighbouring lines.

Comment: Yes ! 
The elevation of the selected line is 100m, the elevation of the linked-line (the left side neighbourg) is the same (100m).
But the two other neighbouring lines, top and bottom, are respectively 95m and 105m high.

Comment: I Noticed that some of the high changing were triggered by Z different cote between two adjacent lines. But i tried to fix this problem by modificating the table, and unfortunately it doesnt work.
But at least I noticed were the problem is, when I worked I should have duplicated lines with different informations, creating a changing that seems to be interpretated sometimes as an altitude changing.
Thank you for the clue !